# Is there a better method than asOpt to convert json into a model

Tags: scala, playframework-2.6

I am using `JsValue`'s `asOpt` to convert a `json` into a model `T`. My issue is that the `json` parsing is failing and I am getting `None` but there is no descriptive error message which indicates what is the issue with the `json`. Is there a better method than `asOpt` which I could use?

The code which converts `JsValue` to model is

```
implicit val myDataReads:Reads[MyData] = (
    (JsPath \ "field1").readNullable[UUID] and
    (JsPath \ "field2").read[String] and
      (JsPath \ "field3").read[List[String]] and
      (JsPath \ "field4").read[Seq[Byte]] and
      (JsPath \ "field5").read[String] and
      (JsPath \ "field6").read[Set[String]] and
      (JsPath \ "field7").read[String] and
      (JsPath \ "field8").read[String]
    )(MyData.apply _)
```

The above isn't descriptive. I thought to create my custom `Reads` but I am stuck. So far I have written:

```
val myDataReads = new Reads[MyData] {

//the JsValue passed to this reads should conform to structure expected by MyData
def reads(jsv:JsValue) = JsResult = {
//I want to pick each field, check its value and print error is something is wrong
  val uuidOptionReads:Reads[Option[UUID]] = (JsPath \ "field1").readNullable[UUID]; //not sure if this is correct
  //now I have got new Reads but how do I get uuid from here?
uuidOptionReads.reads(/*reads expects a JsValue but I don't know what to pass here.*/)
/*I want to repeat the above logic for other fields*/
}

  }
```

Comment: Rather use `.validate`

Comment: I was able to solve my problem using `validate` - `myjson.validateOpt[MyData]`. Thanks. Happy to accept your answer.